# Rename illegal column names with PHP for mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, renaming

I have a column named "read" in my table.
When I try to perform operations on it, PHP tells me there's an error surround 'read'. From previous experience with this kind of errors, I have determined that the column name 'read' is illegal.
The problem is that I can't rename the column with PHP. Every time I try, I get an error (the same error, actually).
When I go in PHPMyAdmin, and change it there, it works perfectly afterwards.

Any ideas on how I can change the column name with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "rename", do you mean you're trying to modify the table definition itself, like with `ALTER TABLE`? If so, there shouldn't be a difference between your PHP code and PHPMyAdmin (since the latter is itself just PHP code). The only problem you could run into is if you're logging in as a different database user in your PHP code than you are in PHPMyAdmin. You need to make sure the user has [ALTER privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_alter) on that table.

If you're only talking about running normal queries on the table, and just want to stop the syntax error from occurring, then you can just wrap your field and/or table names in backticks - i.e. <kbd>`</kbd> usually on the same key as the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> on the number bar - and MySQL will be able to distinguish between the field name and the reserved word.

Comment: I tried that before posting the question, but it didn't work =(

Comment: @user866339 If this didn't work, then why did you accept my answer? I can assure you that the backticks work, but if you would like to post your code as an edit to your question, I'd be happy to take a second look at your code. From your comment on Dani's answer, it looks like you're using the wrong quote. You need to use a backtick, not a single quote. It's hard to use backticks in comments, since SO uses them to denote code blocks. This wiki page can show you what a backtick is though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent

Answer (score 5):

Use backticks around the table name, like this:

```
select * from `read`
```

It tells MySQL that you are referring to a name and not a keyword.

Comment: @user866339 No. Those are single quotes. You need to use backticks. I left you more information as a response to your comment on my answer.